# ng2-smart-table update list dynamically

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

I have an ngx-form-settings and a dropdown object in a column. This dropdown should be populated by a query (through a service call).

This is the *settings*:

```
site: {
title: 'SITE',
    type: 'html',
            editor: {
              type: 'list',
              config: {
                list: [],
              },
            }
          },
```

if I do this, it works (of curse this is not what I need as the setList must be into the getData.subscribe):

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getData().subscribe((data: any) => {
    });
    this.setList();
  }
```

if I do this, it doesn't work:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getData().subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.setList();
    });
  }
```

where set list is just this (for now):

```
  setList() {
    this.settings.columns.site.editor.config.list = [{ value: 'Option 1', title: 'Option 1' },
            { value: 'Option 2', title: 'Option 2' },
            { value: 'Option 3', title: 'Option 3' },
            { value: 'Option 4', title: 'Option 4' },
            { value: 'Option 5', title: 'Option 5' },
            { value: 'Option 6', title: 'Option 6' },
    ];
  }
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to figure this out,

The ngOnInit is called and set settings.  Point is that the subscribe (in the case that doesn't work) return immediately and the ngOnInit cannot initialize the list. "Settings" is not dynamically updated, so to speak. A workaround I've found is this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getData().subscribe((data: any) => {
    this.settings.columns.site.editor.config.list = [
        { value: 'Option 1', title: 'Option 1' },
        { value: 'Option 2', title: 'Option 2' },
        { value: 'Option 3', title: 'Option 3' },
        { value: 'Option 4', title: 'Option 4' },
        { value: 'Option 5', title: 'Option 5' },
        { value: 'Option 6', title: 'Option 6' }];
    });
    this.settings = Object.assign({}, this.settings);
}
```

when the service returns and executes the subscribed method the only chance is to reload the whole *Settings* structure.

```
this.settings = Object.assign({}, this.settings);
```

Comment: Works like charm. Thanks mate

Comment: same problem, can't believe we don't have native solution

Comment: you are my hero!. Thanks